# $resource, Data.query({other_id: 1}) is retrieving all the data

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have some information in a rest api:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'test',
    'other_id': 1
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'test2',
    'other_id': 1
},
{
     'id': 3,
     'name': 'test3',
     'other_id': 2
}
```

I try using Data.query({other_id: 1}) and Data.query({'other_id': 1}) but both retrieve the 3 rows and I want the first and the second row

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the $resource get method instead of query. Query will return a collection, while get returns a single element.

An example from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123});
```

### Edit

Query cannot return a subset of the collection, it returns the entire collection served by your endpoint. In order to get a subset of the objects in a collection, you have two options:

1. Modify your backend endpoint to expect a list of ids, and only return those objects who have a matching id.

   ```
   var data = Data.query({ids:'1,2'});
   ```
2. Get all the objects, and simply filter the irrelevant ones out.

   ```
   var desiredObjects = [1,2];
   Data.query().then(function(data) {
       data.filter(function(a) {
           return desiredObjects.indexOf(a.id) > -1
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Yeah, but I want a collection with: id 1 and 2

Comment: You will want to use query. Send a list of all the ids you want. Then your backend will read this list and return only the objects with matching ids.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer to give you more detail.

Comment: and which is the best way of filtering? with a for it's ok? or there is a best way of filter using angularjs??

Comment: See my edit, using the javascript filter method is the most concise way. A simple for loop is absolutely fine in this situation as well.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot, I search a lot for an answer

Comment: I can not upvoute until 15 bandages :/

Comment: I see, you can still accept the answer, you will get 2 points for doing it.

Comment: click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. See this page for more detail:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work